# Read in two text file lists and write out 1 line from to a text file

Tags: windows, loops, powershell, scripting

I need to create a powershell script that reads in two text files with lists.
The first list is used to identify the remote computers that will have a file appended to it.
The second list is the key phrase that needs to be appended to the file.

List 1:
Computer1 
Computer2
Computer3

List 2: 
ABC
DEF
GHI

Script would loop through each pointing to a file say C:\temp\help.txt on each of the remote computers and write 1 line from List 2.

So Example: When the script runs it goes out to List 1, finds that computer 1 is first and opens the file \computer1\C$\temp\help.txt, it would then grab the first line from List 2 and write to the file ABC. Close the file and go on to Computer 2. Computer 2 would be \computer2\C$\temp\help.txt and would grab the 2nd item from List 2 and write to it DEF save and move on.

It's been hard to find any help reading in and looping through 2 lists. Or perhaps I am thinking of it wrong. I have gotten to Get-Content to read in the file and foreach($x for text1) can go through 1 of the text files loops but can not figure out how to loop through the 2nd text file.

Comment: Would it be better if I were to try and combine the two text files into a CSV then process it?

Comment: It would indeed be nicer if you would have something more concrete, let it be csv file, or just text file of certain format, for example: `computer1 c:\1.txt` and so on. It would be way easier to update for you. You would read it line by line, split it by space and go do your action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processing side-by-side arrays is always a pain, and tends to be error prone.  Ideally, as suggested, the computer names and strings would be together in a CSV or something.

But as is, something like this should get you on the right track.  You might have to fiddle with newlines at the beginning/end of the strings a bit.

```
$machines = Get-Content .\MachineList.txt
$strings = Get-Content .\StringsList.txt

if($machines.Count -ne $strings.Count){ throw 'Counts do not match' }

for($i = 0; $i -lt $strings.Count; $i++)
{
  $path = "\\$($machines[$i])\C`$\temp\help.txt"   # unc path
  $strings[$i] | Add-Content $path
}
```

If you have it in a CSV like

```
Config.csv
---------
ComputerName,String
machine1,string1
machine2,string2
machine3,string3
```

Then you could simplify to this:

```
Import-Csv .\Config.csv |%{
  $_.String | Add-Content "\\$($_.ComputerName)\C`$\temp\help.txt"
}
```

Comment: The top on works for two lists. Couldn't get the CSV to work properly.